# Todays Date in Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Can Someone Help me in getting Today's date in the handlebar file ? 
The Output should be something like "Today is Thursday" .
 `

```
<script>
  var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDay();
  var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var x = document.getElementById("MyP").innerHTML;
  x = x + daylist[day];
  document.getElementById("MyP").innerHTML = x;
</script>

 <h2 class="page-header">Dashboard</h2>
<p>Welcome to {{user.username}}</p>
<p id="MyP"></p>
```

`

I've been trying this way but somehow it isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Make sure the `<script>` tag is after your HTML since otherwise when your script executes, the HTML is not ready yet.

```
<h2 class="page-header">Dashboard</h2>
<p>Welcome to {{ user.username }}</p>
<p id="MyP">Today is </p>

<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    document.getElementById("MyP").innerHTML += daylist[day];
</script>
```